# My search returns null "page 404"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I have created search on MVC.Net C# and and I am using ADO.Net /SQL server 2008 technology in below I have copied and pasted my controller page & my View page... Will you be kind and look at my codes and give me feedback that why this doesn't return any result, but an error? This error happens when I submit the search button!

Controller:

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    Context db = new Context();


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Report(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page) //adds a page parameter, a current sort order parameter, and a current filter parameter to the method 
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;   // the view with the current sort order to keep the sort order the same while paging
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;  //maintain the filter settings during paging, and it must be restored to the text box when the page is redisplayed
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;  // provides the view with the current filter strin


         var reports = from s in db.DRs
                      select s;

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
         {
             reports = db.DRs.Where(s => s.DR_REPORT_NUM.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                               || ...
         }
        #region Sorting
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name_desc":
                reports = reports.OrderByDescending(s => s.DR_INM_LAST_NAME);
                break;
            case "Date":
                reports = reports.OrderBy(s => s.DR_INCIDENT_DATE);
                break;
            case "Date_desc":
                reports = reports.OrderByDescending(s => s.DR_INCIDENT_DATE); break;
            default: //Name ascending
                reports = reports.OrderBy(s => s.DR_INM_LAST_NAME);
                break;
        }
        #endregion


        int pageSize = 10;   // converts the inmate query to a single page of forms in a collection type that supports paging.
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(reports.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

and my View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "Form", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))

{
    <p>
        <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div style="width: 50%; float: left; margin-left: -5%" id="left">
                <h3>Find Report: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)<input type="submit" value="Search" /></h3>
```

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly

Comment: Do you get the error when the page loads or when you submit the form?

Comment: @Luke101 I get the error when I submit my request to search! On search button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the action attribute  from

**From**

```
[HttpGet]
```

**To**

```
[HttpPost]
```